# How do I disable BalloonToolbar at runtime from javascript in ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

How do I enable/disable BalloonToolbar(That is: Controls if it should popup when the user selects text in the editor) at runtime from javascript in ckeditor 5.

I tried to use

```
var plugin=this.plugins.get("BalloonToolbar");
plugin.isEnabled=false;
```

But this does not work. The BalloonToolbar still popup when after that code.